# Best image format for/in CUDA image processing

Tags: image, image-processing, cuda, format

i am new to image-processing in CUDA.
I am currently learning whatever i can about this.
Can anyone tell me what is the appropriate format (extension of image) for storing and accessing image files so that CUDA processing would have the most efficiency.

And y does all the sample cuda programs for image processing use .ppm file format for images.

And can i convert the images in other format to that format.

And how can i access those files (CUDA Code)?

Answer (score 1):

Most image formats are created for efficient *exchange* of images, ie. on media (hard disk), the internet, etc.

For computation, the most useful representation of an image is usually in some raw, uncompressed format.

CUDA doesn't have any intrinsic functions that are used to manipulate an image in one of the interchange formats (e.g. .jpg, .png, .ppm, etc.)  You should use some other library to convert an image in one of the interchange formats to a raw uncompressed format, and then you can operate on it directly in host code or in CUDA device code.  Since CUDA doesn't recognize any interchange format, there is no one format that is correct or best to use.  It will depend on other requirements you may have.

The sample programs that have used the `.ppm` format have simply done so for convenience.  There are plenty of sample codes out there that use other formats such as .jpg or .bmp to store an image used by a CUDA program.

Comment: I read somewhere that, if I was only integer calculations while programming in CUDA ( GPU) , there is no relative increase is speed while compared to ordinary programming ( programming in CPU), is it true???

Comment: This is a completely different question, right?  SO question/answers are not for chat purposes.  I suggest posting a new question.  And no, I don't think it's true that GPUs aren't useful for integer calculations.

Comment: To say.exactly, for image processing, as u know the data.of the images which I am.planning on using only contains int ( R, G, B - only has.integer values ). So only I am asking this.

Comment: You can still experience speed-up on the GPU.  The entire `npp` [library](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/index.html) can handle integer pixel values and demonstrate speed-up for various operations.